# How to track zip file download without an onclick event?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a zip file url http://www.mycompany.com/download/test.zip

I have to send this url via e-mail to my customers.

How can I track the number of downloads using Google analytics?

I have tried adding utm_source to this url but of no use. http://www.mycompany.com/download/test.zip?utm_source=downld

Also, onclick event is not possible because there is no webpage opening on click of the zip file url. When the customer clicks on the url in his/her email, the zip file starts downloading.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use event tracking on the onclick event:

```
<a href="/path/to/doc.pdf" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'PDF', 'doc.pdf']);">Download</a>
```

Look in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide to see what the parameters mean.

Of course you could also use a virtual pageview (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews) with your zip Files url (which would affect bounce rates and average visits time etc).

Comment: the problem is that the zip file is in an email, not on a regular web page.

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid and didn't read properly. I'm not sure what's the custom here at stackexchange - do I delete wrong answers ?

Comment: well...your answer is somewhat relevant as a "next step," if the OP takes my advice about moving the zip link out of the email and on to a landing page..

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly track this under your current setup.  You can look at your server logs to see how many times the file was requested, but that may not necessarily give you an accurate count, especially if the file is available for download elsewhere.

Although..I suppose you could write a server-side script that would make a request to GA (e.g. a POST request via CURL), and then have the script serve the document afterwards. You would then add some code in your .htaccess file to redirect the `file.zip` request to the script. This is doable but kinda complex (it's the same principle as dynamic images (e.g. captcha), if you want to search for more info)..

The easier route would be to create and point to a landing page instead of directly to the file. The visitor would then click on a link and go to a page that has a big shiny download button that you *can* add GA click tracking to.  As a bonus, you can add campaign tracking to the landing page link in your emails, to track that visitors came from the email.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am a php developer but a newbie to curl. I would like to implement your solution of server-side script(POST via curl). Please suggest me some tutorials or examples to do this.

Comment: Well that wasn't really your question.  I suggest you mark this question and start a new question and maybe someone will give you a more detailed answer, but I'm pretty sure if you look, you will probably find code someone else has already made for doing server-side GA requests. So your script would first do that, then you would basically `file_get_contents` on the zip, set the headers to be for zip file, and then just echo out the `file_get_contents` of the zip as the response.